# How to trace memory leaks in android application

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Actually i have developed one android application, but when performing some operations out of memory is getting and application is getting crashed. How to identify memory leaks???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse has a integrate profiler tool, called `MAT` - Memory Analayzer Tool. You can use it to analize the heap of your application. It's quit simple to install. From Eclipse click on

```
Help -> Install new software
```

then from the `DDMS` perspective, in the Decices section, you can select the process of your app, and clicking on `"Dump HPROF File"` the tool will open with the dump of the current `heap`.

[here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) is an example of usage ot the MAT tool, from the android developer blog.